# How to use a tuple's elements as indexes to reach a list's elements-haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of tuples, which I am trying to use its elements to reach a nested list's elements.

```
list = [["c","a","b"],["k","l","m"]]
indexTuple = [(0,1),(1,1),(1,2)]
```

this way I need to check whether there is an "a" in one of the elements of the list corresponding to my indexTuple's elements. My attempt so far;

```
seekinga :: [[[Char]]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [(Int,Int)]
seekinga list x y width 
        | list !!(map fst indexTuple) !!(map snd indexTuple) == "a" = [(fst indexTuple,snd indexTuple)]
        | otherwise = [()]
    where indexTuple = [(x,y) | x <- [x-width..x+width], y <- [y-width..y+width]]
```

this obviously does not work, because the !! operator wants integers to work on, but map returns lists. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You really have two separate concerns: given two numbers, how do you index into a nest list and how do you get two numbers out of a tuple.

The first problem is easy to solve just by looking at types. You know how to index into *one* list: `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`. Here, `a` can be *anything*, including a nested list. So, given `[[[Char]]]`, we can use `!!` to get a `[[Char]]`. And, since this is a list itself, we can use `!!` *again* to get a `[Char]`. (`[Char]` is just `String`, in case you don't realize.)

So all we need to do here is use `!!` then use it again on the result of the first one.

Now, how do we actually get the two numbers out? This is where we use pattern matching. We can just match against a tuple with a let statement:

```
let (i, j) = tuple in ...
```

Now just put the two together and you're set.

Comment: I think you did a better job motivating how to go about solving the problem with proper problem solving skills, instead of jumping directly into code like I did.

Answer (score 3):

So you can view an element with:

```
> list !! 1 !! 2
"m"
```

So lets make this a function:

```
:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let index lst  i j= lst !! i !! j
```

And lets `filter` out those indexs which do not point to "a"

```
> filter (\(i, j) -> index list i j == "a") indexTuple
[(0,1)]
```

If instead
    list = [["c","a","b"],["k","l","a"]]

then

```
> filter (\(i, j) -> index list i j == "a") indexTuple
[(0,1),(1,2)]
```

Using `!!` may not be your best option however, in fact it probably is not. I tried to break out the two parts of the problem, as I understood it, access the element and filter for indexes.

Comment: btw what does :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction thing do, can you explain it please

Comment: The [wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) can explain some.  Try defining `let a = (+)` in ghci with and with out the monomorphism restriction set and use `:t a` to find a's type to see an example of the effect it has.